# Check if sqlcmd was successful

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I am using sqlcmd to run an sql query in a batch file. I would then like to – depending on if the sql query has been successfuly executed or not – do something.

```
sqlcmd -some flags -Q "Query"
iF successful (
    do this
) ELSE (
    do that
)
```

Thanks – I am new to batch programming by the way.

Comment: Does the sqlcmd return an errorlevel? Put this after your sqlcmd to see if it does. `echo %errorlevel%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exit code from a program is represented by the ERRORLEVEL environment variable. Use `if /?` for more details.

```
sqlcmd -some flags -Q "Query"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    do this failed
) ELSE (
    do that success
)
```

Comment: You need to remove the % symbols or change it to `if %errorlevel%==1`.

Comment: OK, this works great! But I wonder how I could catch the case where `sqlcmd` worked but the `sql query` didn't?

Comment: I am not sure for sqlcmd. In Oracle sqlplus, the statements `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1;` and `WHENEVER OSERROR  EXIT 2;` will send these values as the exit code.

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way is with [conditional execution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) (I think sqlcmd has different error codes in case of not successful execution):

```
sqlcmd -some flags -Q "query" &&(
   echo SUCCESS
   echo do something 
   color
)||(
  echo failed
  echo do something else
)
```

Comment: The sqlcmd outputs the result given from sql. I use the `-o` flag but I can't imagine that this is the reason. Where do I get the error codes?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer @npocmaka suggested, it could done using flag `-b`. For example,

```
(sqlcmd -b -Q "SELECT * FROM sys.tables" && echo success) || echo failed
```